# Trying to remember book - earth surrounded by wires/cables, elites have star seal to signify status

Tags: story-identification

The plot summary goes something like: A boy is born on a remote outpost in space. Elites in this society have some kind of sun or star seal that signifies their status. The boy's father (or father figure to him) does not have that seal, but when the boy gets older, he has his first sexual relationship with a female scientist who does have the seal.

The boy - now a young man - eventually finds a way to return closer to earth, possibly by forging or faking the seal. Earth is surrounded by a web of cables and wires, so space society is separated from surface society. The boy spends some time in the midst of space society, but some kind of catastrophic accident occurs, possibly through a revolt on the surface of Earth. The boy finally returns to the surface of Earth and has to conceal his seal from revolutionaries he meets there.

I read this book more than 30 years ago, so it was probably written in th elate 1970s or early 1980s. I would love to find it and re-read! Thanks for any help - I've had no luck with google searches on this.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. This is a nice first post. I hope one of our experts is able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a lot like LIFEBURST by Jack Williamson, published 1984. Not positive, though!

Comment: Amazing. That's it, Lee. Many thanks. I knew as soon as I saw book cover in Google images - although plot summary as described in actual book review is WAY more complicated than i recall. Really looking forward to reading this again. Appreciate your response!